# To find if a number is fibonacci or not

Tags: python, fibonacci

I am a student, new to python. I am trying to code a program that will tell if a user input number is fibonacci or not.

```
num=int(input("Enter the number you want to check\n"))
temp=1
k=0
a=0
summ=0
while summ<=num:
    summ=temp+k
    temp=summ
    k=temp
    if summ==num:
        a=a+1
        print("Yes. {} is a fibonnaci number".format(num))
        break
if a==0:
    print("No. {} is NOT a fibonacci number".format(num))
#The program is working for only numbers upto 2.
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You have `k=temp` right after `temp=summ`, so `k` and `temp` are the same number, instead of the last two Fibonacci numbers as you seem to intend.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need quite so many variables. A Fibonacci integer sequence can be generated with the single assignment

```
a, b = b, a + b

# Short for
#     temp = a
#     a = b
#     b = temp + b
```

Repeated applications sets `a` to the numbers in the pattern in sequence. The choice of initial values for `a` and `b` determine which exact sequence you get. The Fibonacci numbers are generated when `a = 0` and `b = 1` are used.

```
a = 0
b = 1

a, b = 1, 0 + 1  # 0, 1
a, b = 1, 1 + 1  # 1, 2
a, b = 2, 1 + 2  # 2, 3
a, b = 3, 2 + 3  # 3, 5
# etc
```

(As another example, the Lucas numbers are generated if you start with `a = 2` and `b = 1`.)

All you need to do is return `True` if `n == a` at each step, iterating until `n > a`. If `n` wasn't one of the `a` values generated by the loop, you'll return `False`.

```
n = int(input(...))
a = 0
b = 1
while a <= n:
    if n == a:
        return True
    a, b = b, a + b
return False
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something like this:

```
fib_terms = [0, 1]  # first two fibonacci terms

user_input= int(input('Enter the number you want to check\n'))

# Add new fibonacci terms until the user_input is reached
while fib_terms[-1] <= user_input:
    fib_terms.append(fib_terms[-1] + fib_terms[-2])

if user_input in fib_terms:
    print(f'Yes. {user_input} is a fibonacci number.')
else:
    print(f'No. {user_input} is NOT a fibonacci number.')
```

Answer (score 0):

welcome to the python community.

In Your code `temp` means the previous number and `k` means the previous number of `temp`. The problem is that you change the `temp` before you assign the next value to `k`. To solve that you just have to sawp the lines 8 and 9. In the new order you first assign the value of `temp` to `k` then `summ` to `temp`. That's it!

I suggest you to do it by a list in this way:
`fib[i] = fib[i-1] + fib[i-2]`
It will improve the clarity of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
def fibonacci_list(limit):
    u_n_1 = 1
    u_n_2 = 1
    u_n = 1
    out_list = [u_n]
    while u_n <= limit:
        out_list.append(u_n)
        u_n = u_n_1 + u_n_2
        u_n_2 = u_n_1
        u_n_1 = u_n
    return out_list


def is_fibonacci_number(n):
    if n in fibonacci_list(n):
        return True
    return False


def main():
    n = int(input('Enter a number:'))
    if is_fibonacci_number(n):
        print(str(n) + ' is a fibonacci number ')
    else:
        print(str(n) + ' is not a fibonacci number ')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Seems long but easy to understand

Comment: making a list and comparing it to the number is a solution and works but it's too long and inefficient, check @chepner his answer seems very good and practical.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool checkfibonacci(int n)
    {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 1;
        if (n == a || n == b) return true;
        int c = a + b;
        while(c <= n)
        {
            if(c == n) return true;
            a = b;
            b = c;
            c = a + b;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Something like this will do it.